# Loop through rows and edit them in VBA Excel2010

Tags: excel, for-loop, rows, vba

I am creating an interface with data entries.
These entries (1 per row) shall then be added to another entry in the same row.
Apparently it does not select the right rows and starts above row 4.

```
For Each row In Worksheets("A").Range("D4:D11") 'Start at row 4

    .Cells(5, row) = wse.Cells(6, row) + wse.Cells(4, row)  
    'This is supposed to add entries from each looped row to cells in columns D and F into E.

Next row
```

Some of the entries even appear in columns A and B, while others appear in rows way below.

I am quite surprised that I was not able to find a solution for my problem, but maybe you can help me :)

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `row` isn't what you think it is, it's a `Range` object.

You want something like:

```
For Each Rng In Worksheets("A").Range("D4:D11") 'Start at row 4

    Worksheets("A").Cells(5, Rng.Row) = wse.Cells(6, Rng.Row) + wse.Cells(4, Rng.Row)

Next Rng
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot sir!